# Flex: Align multiple items as a table

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, flexbox

Trying to align some subsections of a row more nicely. I've managed to get the "Read more"-button on the same line, using flex: 1;. However, I can't seem to get the top of the images and start of the first paragraphs to align nicely.

The layout is a series of divs, with articles inside of them:

```
<div class="row-X">
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
  </article>
</div>
```

This is the result I'm looking for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBM5D.jpg

And this is what I got: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqveNq

Comment: the site uses image and you are using real code so a line of text is affecting the layout?

Comment: Unless the two `main` elements share a common parent even `flexbox` wont help here. That's just not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

**[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNWjgz)**

```
header{
  min-height:140px;
}
```

in this case give a min height to header.

Comment: That were my intial solution to the problem, but it ended up looking odd for the rows with minimal headers. Thought maybe there is a flexbox solution to the problem as well ..?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look: **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/01/pen/BNeVXG)**

### CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#img-1 {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

#img-2 {
  height: 90px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

.row-2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
.row-2 > * {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row-2 > * main {
  flex: 1;
}

article {
  float: left;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```